# if lt IE 9 - not loading

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I have the following code in the header of a test site:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/ie8.css" />
<![endif]-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css">
```

But when I test this on IE10 in document mode IE8 the ie8.css doesn't load at all.
Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Add a blank line before and after your code blocks so that it works properly.  I've done this for you.

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer 10 was the first Internet Explorer browser to [no longer support Conditional Comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801214%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This support is also not present when you're emulating older browsers.

If you wish to test this in Internet Explorer 8, I would encourage you to instead consider downloading a free Virtual Machine containing Internet Explorer 8 from http://modern.ie, or spin up a virtual instance of Windows XP and Internet Explorer 8 over at http://browserstack.com.